# Capybara -> how to use the result of native method

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

using `page.find( 'some-element' ).native` consistently returns a string, say '4'.  Documentation states it returns some object that allows me to access native methods.  Anyone ever run into this?

Capybara version is `1.1.2`
Capybara-Webkit version is `0.12.1`

Comment: Dang, I was just about to ask this question again. I guess I'm in the twilight zone or something on this one.

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm getting exactly the same result:
  Failure/Error: page.find('.event').native.location.y.should be > 0
  undefined method `location' for "4":String

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution was to upgrade ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 and all the nice dependencies that go along with it.

Comment: Weird, I'm already at 1.9.3.  What else did you end up upgrading during the process?  Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code ( and implicitly Gemfile ) anymore; and we were using so many gems we didn't really have to use, I really can't even give you a good guess.  It was a real hodgepodge.

Comment: same boat here.  thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be using Capybara Webkit, which represents internal nodes as Integers.  You can still access the native Rack::Test node using:

```
page.find( 'some-element' ).base.native
```

More Details here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/634